# Github API /repos/:owner/:repo/contributors returns an empty object

Tags: github-api, github-api-v3

When running the following command, I get en empty object:

```sh
$ curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/wix/DetoxInstruments/stats/contributors"
{

}
```

In my original script, I provide an `access_token`, but it's not necessary to demonstrate the problem.

It seems to happen for that specific repo. What could be the reason?

Comment: Strange, it seems to be stuck on the web as well:
https://github.com/wix/DetoxInstruments/graphs/contributors

Comment: It seems like a bug on their end. I've opened a support ticket with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, and GitHub support fixed it on their backend.

Comment: not yet I think. I'm facing the same issue